# How to get dynamic CheckBox Id

Tags: android

I have created checkbox dynamically. Based on the require list size just am creating new dynamic check box in a repeated manner and am also setting the Id for that. Now i want to do check it in other loop.

```
  for(int i=0;i<require.size();i++)
        {
            //From Requirements
            requirement=require.get(i);
            RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            rl1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewdesign);
            l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            req1 = new CheckBox(getActivity());
            rl1.addView(req1);
            req1.setId(Integer.parseInt(requirement.r_id));
            Log.i("getid",Integer.toString(req1.getId()));
            li.add(Integer.toString(req1.getId()));
        }
```

In this loop am just checking element of li and proj_require1 values. If both are equal then I want to make the CheckBox as checked. For that i have written the code here.

```
for(int i=0;i<li.size();i++)
        {
            //li.get(i);
            req1 = (CheckBox) container.findViewById(i);
            String sr = req1.toString();
            for(int j=0;j<proj_require1.size();j++)
            {
                pr = proj_require1.get(j);
                if(sr.equals(pr.rid))
                {
                    req1.setChecked(!req1.isChecked());
                }
                else
                {
                    req1.setChecked(req1.isChecked());
                }
            }
        }
```

But my doubt is in first loop am creating the CheckBox based on the size of require object. So every time it creates the CheckBox inside the loop. But in second loop am trying to access the checkbox which am created in the first loop. Could anyone please help me to solve this problem? The only way is i can create the CheckBox in the first loop. I want to access it in other loop. Is it possible?

Comment: you could use findViewById on the container to retrieve the checkbox

Comment: @blackbelt Consider I have 50 requirements and am showing everything in the checkbox. Requirements are master which comes from the server. I have to display everything. At the same time out of 50 requirements there are only 10 requirements are checked. So i want to check the checkbox based on that 10 requirements which is again sent from the server. If you see the first loop , just i have created the new check boxes based on the requirement size. req = new CheckBox(getActivity()). How can i do check it in other loop. This is what my question? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: it is the same. You can use findViewById to retrieve the 10 checkboxes you want to check

Comment: @blackbelt Please check my code. I have edited the second loop as like as you suggested. But it is not working. If it is not correct then could you please give me an example?